# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to get picture from filepath concerning the BitMapFactory.decodeFile for drawing bitmap in Canvas and get this exception:

```
 Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/content:/media/external/images/media/40: open failed: ENOENT (No such file 
or directory)
02-02 10:03:19.793 3371-3371/com.group.digit.razvoj.appointment 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

but when i use that filepath to setImage in Fragment it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
 String urilogo = helper.getUri();
        File imgFile = new  File(urilogo);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

In Fragment where it works:

```
String urilogo = helper.getUri();        
    if(urilogo!= null || urilogo!= "") {
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(urilogo));
    }
```

Comment: `/content:/media/external/images/media/40` is not a file URi obviously. You can't open it as file.

Comment: it retuns filepath.

Comment: `/content:/media/external/images/media/40` is not a file path

Comment: What it is than?

Comment: it opens a stream from that URI. You can do as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not bothered about file name, you can use [InputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) as:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(urilogo);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
```

If above code doesn't work and  `helper.getUri()` is a `file` Uri the use:

```
String urilogo = helper.getUri();
File imgFile = new File(new URI(urilogo));
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: File imgFile = new  File(URI(urilogo));  dont work...i get error that URI(urilogo) need method to be called

Comment: add `new` before `URI(urilogo)` and check

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI: content://media/external/images/media/41
                                                                                      at java.io.File.checkURI(File.java:223)